# Date for titleForHeaderInSection with FetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data, nsdateformatter, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsdatecomponents

I have a property `@NSManaged public var sectionKeyDate: Date?` I am trying to use for the `sectionKey`. I'm having an issue getting the resulting string from the `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` to format into a `Date`, to then be converted back into a formatted string.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        
        guard let sectionInfo = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-DD"
        print("sectionInfo.name: ", sectionInfo.name)
        print("Date: ", formatter.date(from: sectionInfo.name))
        
        guard let date = formatter.date(from: sectionInfo.name) else { return "Error" }
        let string = formatter.string(from: date)
        return string
    }
```

The conversion from a string to date is failing and return nil.

```
sectionInfo.name:  2021-03-25 05:00:00 +0000
Date:  nil
```

(1) I'm not sure how to format this correctly.
(2) I'm not entirely sure if using a `Date` for the `sectionKeyPath` is an ok thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in getting the correct `dateFormat`.

```
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
        
        let date = formatter.date(from: sectionInfo.name)
```